# Get AD group membership for the current user on another domain

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a bit of code to get all of the AD groups for the user currently logged in:

```
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName);

        // find a user
        UserPrincipal adUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, user);

        if (adUser == null)
        {
            Logger.Error("Could not find related Active Directory user");
            return;
        }
        GetUserDetailsFromGroupMembership(adUser.GetGroups().Select(g => g.Name));
```

This will get all the groups the current user is part of on its registered domain. My username is part of the "EUR" domain, but I also have memberships on the "USA" domain. How do I also query groups in the other domains?

Answer (score 4):

`GetGroups()` gets all the groups from domains in the same forest, so I have to assume that your two domains are not in the same forest, but are trusted by each other.

I don't know of a way to do this with the `AccountManagement` namespace, but this is how you would do it with `DirectorySearcher`.

When accounts get added to groups on an external, trusted domain, they show up as Foreign Security Principal objects, which contain the SID of the account. So that's what you have to search for. You already have the account in the `adUser` variable, so I'm using `adUser.Sid` here.

I assume you will always be searching the one other domain, so you can hard code the `distinguishedName` of the other domain in the first line.

```
var otherDomainDN = "DC=usa,domain,DC=com";
var ds = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{otherDomainDN}"),
    $"(&(objectClass=group)(member=CN={adUser.Sid},CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,{otherDomainDN}))");
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");

var otherDomainGroups = new List<string>();
foreach (SearchResult g in ds.FindAll()) {
    otherDomainGroups.Add(g.Properties["cn"][0].ToString());
}
```

After this, `otherDomainGroups` will be a list of the names of the other groups.

Comment: There may be a missing closing parentheses at the end of dsand unfortunatelly the solution is not working for me :(

Comment: You're right about the missing closing parenthesis - I fixed it. There can be many reasons it's not working for you. If you'd like some help, you can start your own question and post the code you're using.

Comment: I have no idea what I had wrong. Did it again from scratch reading MSDN docs and at the end I have same code as you and it is working. So your code is OK, thank you!